# Why can I not find the og table after installing Organic Groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am using [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)  module.

After installation why do I not find the `og` table?

I only have these five tables:

[image: just five table]

Here is a screenprint from the Drupal log with messages from around the time the og module was enabled:

[image: log message]

**Note**: I installed the og module using a new Drupal site (which doesn't have any other contributed modules enabled yet), and I tried a disable/uninstall of it. Then re-installed the module but it did not fix this problem.

Comment: in og.install,  it has the code:/**
 * Return the schema for upgrade 7000.
 */
function og_schema_7000_info() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['og'] = array(............

Comment: When you install og module, you get only these 5 tables.

Comment: BTW, who even looks for tables after installing a module ?

Comment: Because I am using og module to develop my site, I don't want to use panels module and views module, so I need to know where is Drupal 7 Organic Group Data stored. and I can't find og table, so I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal 7 version of Organic Groups doesn't have an `og` table. The Drupal 6 version does, but it's removed as part of the upgrade process, and never exists in the newer version.

You can always find out what tables a module is responsible for by checking its implementation of hook_schema() (in this case [`og_schema()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.install/function/og_schema/7)).

Comment: thanks for your help, I know og table is removed as part of the upgrade process, via function og_schema_7000_info(),  when I enable og module, the upgrade process will run,  isn't it?

Comment: No, updates only run when 1. You're migrating major version or 2. When you run them explicitly. Whatever's in `hook_schema()` is the definitive version of what the _current_ iteration of a module's schema will look like. You can look at `og_schema()`, see that there's no `og` table, and immediately conclude that the module doesn't have such a table (and isn't supposed to)

Comment: Great to see that the "mystery" is resolved. And of course I'm not going to question the fact that the answer from "El maestro" (aka @Clive) is "the" answer. But, am I the only one who wonders "what was the actual question" ... For which this answer seems to be the answer? Too bad (for me) that while I was trying to answer the whatever question with various posibilities, 'somebody' seemed to not like my attempts (as per the downvote I got). Oh well ...   Maybe some day that (anonymous) downvoter will change his/her mind ...

Comment: The question is "why can I not find this table?" And the answer is "because the module doesn't create it", I'm not sure what you're misunderstanding @Pierre. Hint: don't put answers in that cover a broad range of vague possibilities. Always find out what the actual _problem_ is, and work towards fixing that. It's best to do this before answering the question, so you know how to answer

Comment: Case in point, memory limits and reinstalling couldn't possibly have had anything to do with this particular issue, so I think it's reasonable to say your answer is wrong, however well intentioned. You even edited the answer after seeing what the problem was, to include that information, but you left all of the irrelevant stuff in there. We simply don't need every answer to contain an appendix of possible debugging tips, _especially_ when they have nothing to do with the question that was asked

Comment: OK @Clive, thanks for sharing this recommendation. As always "greatly appreciated". I do believe however that occasionally memory limits can be the cause of it also. Especially in case of a site with a lot of modules where you try to enable yet another module (which then produce some error msgs in some log files also though). "Now" the question seems to eliminate those possibilities, but the very first version of the question didn't have all those details. Not sure if that means that "now" I should remove those options again from my answer also. Suggestions on that?

Comment: It's your answer @Pierre.Vriens, you get to decide what you think is relevant! I'm reading it as "here's the answer, and here are some things you could have tried if this wasn't the answer, even though they won't solve the problem because it's already been solved". I find that rather confusing

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure you use the correct Drupal version

The initial version of your question didn't specify which version of Drupal you're using. Though the names of the tables you mentioned are from D7 (not used in D6).

That table was available in D6, as confirmed in the [module's installation process for the 6.x-2.x version of it](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/og/tree/og.install?h=6.x-2.x#n8). But that table is no longer available in D7, as  confirmed also in the [module's installation process for the 7.x-2.x version of it](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/og/tree/og.install#n91).

## Re-install the module

Try a disable/uninstall of the og module, then re-install the module.

Sometimes it helps to restore and/or repair these kinds of problems.

## Increase memory limit

Another option might be that you need to increase the memory size of your Drupal site. And then retry uninstall/reinstall one more time. Because each time you install a module, your site will be using more memory. So at some point (if you never increase the memory), you'll hit your available memory limit.

Assuming this is NOT a multi site, consider editing your `/sites/default/settings.php`, and change the line to set the memory limit. If it is a multi site, then edit the `settings.php` file related to the site where you are experiencing the problem.

That line in settings.php should look similar to this:

```
`ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`
```

The '128M' in it might be some other number. Whatever the number is, try to increase it with like 50%, or maybe even double it to see what happens after you do so (of course do not forget to save the file after increasing that number).

Be aware also that the amount of memory you'll actually need, somehow depends on the number of enabled modules (the more modules you (try to) enable, the more memory you'll need.

If needed, refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/207036 for more details, eg if such 'ini_set' is not yet included in your `settings.php` file. As mentioned in that link: "*Locate the PHP settings section and add that line at the end of that section*".

## Check logfiles

If none of the above helps, then check your log files (both Drupla logs and/or server logs) to find some kind of indication of possible errors.

Comment: thanks, bug I am install og module using a new drupal site, and I had try a disable/uninstall of the og module, then re-install the module.  can not fix this problems.

Comment: but default value is: memory_limit = 128M.

Comment: Well, just as a (temporary) test, try to double it to see what happens. Also, how many contributed modules do you have, something like just a few (a dozen), or like 100, or 200 ?

Comment: it's a new website, just installed og, and it work well, but I don't understand, why can not find og table? can you help me to test it via a new drupal site? thank you very much.

Comment: @Brian You can't find what isn't there