# I have WYSIWYG and CKEditor 3.6.6.1 and want to install the latest CKEditor 4.6.1

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

My goal is to paste images (best if copied from word together with text) directly without uploading them first.

I got a D7 site with WYSIWYG installed. The module tells me it uses the CKEditor 3.6.6.1 library. In fact, there is no CKEditor module installed, but in the libraries path I see a ckeditor folder.

I tried to install the module pasteFromWord, and I found it didn't work with my a local copy of my site. So I looked around, and I found there is a newer version of CKeditor (4.6.1) rewritten with lots of features like embedding pictures, and it is open source too. There is only an older version of CKEditor as a Drupal 7 module, and it is driving me nuts to install anything that works.

I read about problems with WYSIWYG and I disabled it, but I cannot uninstall it, so I cancelled the whole directory under modules. I installed the latest Drupal CKEDitor (Dev) but all I see in my text field is htmlcode in full html mode. There are no editor icons. I put higher values for the memory settings in settings.php, restarted the server, cleared the cache, tried all sorts of thing suggested in [Why does the Wysiwyg module and Ckeditor library not show the CKEditor when editing a node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197905/why-does-the-wysiwyg-module-and-ckeditor-library-not-show-the-ckeditor-when-edit)

All tests are done as user1. By now, I get a simple text field in plain and filtered HTML mode; in full HTML, the text box body simply vanishes.

In Mozilla the Console gives:
TypeError: a(...).on is not a function
 js_8iXNyfjLJ1tJPju6nAtk8ETos8oLn9Arp0f2Z5uBPaQ.js:850:1412
TypeError: CKEDITOR.dialogCommand is not a constructor
 plugin.js:4:43
in http://localhost:8080/drupal7bis/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/SimpleImage/plugin.js which is one of the few plugins I enabled so far (nearly all are installed though because indeed I took the full package) and it reads:
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'SimpleImage', {
    icons: 'simpleimage',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'simpleimage', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'simpleimageDialog' ) );
        editor.ui.addButton( 'SimpleImage', {
            label: 'Add a image',
            icons: 'simpleimage',
            command: 'simpleimage'
        });

```
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'simpleimageDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/simpleimage.js' );
}
```

});

When I disable this plugin, only the first error remains. The body does not vanish any more in full mode, but still no editor appears.
There are no recent records in watchdog...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly thanks to Kevins help I finally managed to get it working.
I started over with a new local copy of my D7 site, cancelled the wysiwyg profiles, disabled and then uninstalled the module (this time it showed up in the uninstall tab) and cancelled its directory as well as the ckeditor folder (in \sites\all\libraries).
I then downloaded the latest **full** ckeditor library (4.6.1) from [Ckeditors site](http://ckeditor.com/download) (don't customize because other plugins did not work with D7/wysiwyg, just the plain full version) and copied the unzipped ckeditor folder back to the libraries folder. Don't install the ckeditors drupal **module**. You must install the wysiwyg **DEV** module instead.
Be aware that it is not enough to choose the ckeditor for your wysiwyg profiles because the editor would not have any plugin button enabled and you would not see any button.

I found that pasting from word text including images without uploading the images first did work only in internet explorer, while in mozilla I had to copy first the text and then the images seperately. In Chrome instead of an image I got an empty rectangle only, but I try to find solutions for that too.

Comment: Yes... WYSIWYG would greatly benefit from a new release. Fortunately, this is vastly easier in Drupal 8.

Comment: I am anxiously awaiting a D8 release that migrates our book structure site :-(

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you need to use the dev version of the WYSIWYG module in order to use CKEditor 4.x. You also need to grab the 'full build' of CKEditor and not a stripped down one. You do not need the *CKEditor* module if you are using the WYSIWYG module. WYSIWYG looks for editors in the given paths (usually libraries) - you have to go get it from ckeditor.com.

The second thing you are describing is adding custom or non-core plugins to CKEditor, which is not as straightforward. "Paste from Word" should be available though once you get WYSWIYG and CKEditor 4.x setup in Drupal 7.

I wrote a [plugin integration once](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_codesnippet) for CKEditor 4.x under WYSIWYG. I do not recall needing any module other than WYSIWYG and the full CKEditor library for getting WYSIWYG to show up. You shouldn't need any other CKEditor modules. But if you are looking to add other plugins on ckeditor.com - you need to get comfortable with the WYSIWYG API in order to properly integrate it if someone else hasn't done so already.

The reason your CKEditor may not be showing on the edit page is likely due to a JS error - I am going to guess either because you are not using WYSIWYG dev branch, or CKEditor is not the right version, or CKEditor is not installed in the correct path. Please add the error from the browser console to the original question along with any watchdog errors.

Comment: Thanks. I added the console messages in my original question.. Awesome, I thought WYSIWYG is for client side editors and that ckeditor is an server side editor. However, I uninstalled CK and installed WYSIWIG DEV. now, but i comes with CK 3.6. again:
hm, here ought to show up my screenshot but it doesn't paste...
How do I manage now to let WYSIWYG see my downloaded version 4.6.1 of the CK libraries?

Comment: WYSIWYG module does not ship with any editors, it simply allows for the installation of many supported editors. The dev version allows for CKEditor 4.x to be used. My guess is you have leftover CKEditor 3.x files somewhere in your application that WYSIWYG picks up on.

Comment: Also, try totally removing WYSIWYG module. Uninstall it, then delete the files, and replace it with the dev version. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/1853550#comment-9213657

Comment: Ok. I did actually delete the wysi folder under modules 'cause it didn't appear under 'Uninstall modules'. I don't know where wysi still gets the 3.6.6. version. Maybe from the database? I cannot find the string in any file on my local site. Perhaps I better restore my original site again locally to start from scratch because by now the local site must be compromised. When you say replace you mean install the dev modul regularly, right? So after installing I just copy ck 4 library somewhere and wysi finds it by itself without configuring any file?

Comment: Some progress: I started over, I cancelled the wysiwyg profiles, disabled and then uninstalled the module and cancelled its directory as well as the ckeditor folder under libraries. I then copied the 4.6.1 library (first my custom building with all plugins) to the libraries folder and installed wysiwyg dev. In Configuration it stated to be unable to detect the editor version and suggested to install the full version. I cancelled the folder again and copied the plain full version 4.6.1.580bcaf so I was able to choose this editor for full html. ONLY STILL NO ICONS SHOW AND NO ERROR IN CONSOLE!?!

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that the configuration of the profile changed drastically and every button is a plugin to enable. I now have a new version of ckeditor to test.
However, the paste from word will show only a rectangle when pasting an image, pointing to my local machine. No automatic upload happens. Can you help me further? Is it not possible to add other plugins to ckeditor or how can this be done? Thanks again.

Comment: I must correctify again and apoligize. In internet explorer immages will automatically upload. Unfortunately in our company most of us don't have it installed. I would need it to work in chrome or at least mozilla.